# Child position in LayoutManager

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LayoutManager, and i want to change the children position's to the right side. I had changed the child.layout method, but it's not solved the problem yet.

How can i change the child.layout(), for the solution?? 
I found [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921175/android-how-to-set-position-of-children-view-in-onlayout) but not working for me

Here is the code of onLayout:

```
@Override
    public void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        //Element position
        //Own position

        int mRowHeight = 0;
        int left, top, right;
        int elementsSizeInRow;
        int actItem = 0;
        int remainAreainRow = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount.length; i++) {
            int mRowWidth = 0;

            elementsSizeInRow = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < rowCount[i]; j++) {
                View child = getChildAt(actItem);

                elementsSizeInRow += child.getMeasuredWidth();
                //Log.v("ItemSizes",":"+child.getMeasuredWidth());
                //Log.v("RowItemSize","RowItemsSize: "+elementsSize);

                left = mRowWidth;
                top = mRowHeight;

                mRowWidth += child.getMeasuredWidth();
                child.layout(left, top, left + child.getMeasuredWidth(), top + child.getMeasuredHeight());
//changed to forexample child.layout(left, top, left + getMeasuredWidth()-(left+child.getMeasuredWidth()), top + child.getMeasuredHeight());   //but it's not a solution               

                actItem++;
                remainAreainRow = getMeasuredWidth() - elementsSizeInRow;

            }

            mRowHeight += rowHeight[i];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, i solved the problem :)
Thank's for the nothing! ;)

Solution:

I calculated the remain size all of a row and i added the onLayout first and third parameter Like this:

```
child.layout(remainAreainRow, top, remainAreainRow + child.getMeasuredWidth(), top + child.getMeasuredHeight());
```

And it's working, the children is on the right side, and the top and bottom gravity can be set in the "Linearlayout android:gravity="center,top,bottom"" on the XML.

Comment: It would be useful for other people if you also post *how* you solved